# jquery gif loader doesn't fade out

Tags: jquery, html, css

i wrote a web page with some script at the end (those script only manage button).
Now i insert a new div below the body tag:

```
<div class="loader">LOADING...</div>
```

this is the css:

```css
.loader {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: #fafafa url(page-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
        text-align: center;
        color: #999;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   

<script type="text/javascript">
          $( document ).ready(function() {
          $('.loader').css({'display':'block'});
                console.log( "document loaded" );});
        $( window ).on( "load", function() {
          $('.loader').fadeOut("slow");
                console.log( "window loaded" );});
        </script>
```

The problem is that the gif doesn't fade out, it remains on the page and load infinitely. How can i solve?
i try the script with another page and it works properly. thank you

Comment: instead of using `display: block;` why not use `$('.loader').fadeIn();` or after the `fadeOut()` set the loader CSS back to `display: none;`

Comment: Sounds like your jquery is not loading correctly. Are there any console errors?

Comment: better $('.loader').show()

Comment: If i use $('.loader').fadeIn(); the page load entirely for a second, then disappear and start the gif; the second solution doesn't work and $('.loader').show() too. There are no console error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this following way? Actually for any loader no need to by default hide because to show by jquery fadeIn() we need to wait for at least jQuery file. So it is better to visible by default. See following approach please and try if it is work for you.

```
.loader {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #fafafa url(page-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
}
```

and:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    $('.loader').fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this kind of thing in my app, try this script please this may help

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#loading').fadeOut('300', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }, 600);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***This code should work for you***

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="loader">LOADING...</div>
  <!-- OTHER TAGS FROM HERE -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.loader {
  display: block;  /*Should Display*/
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #fafafa url(page-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loader').fadeOut(1000);  /*FadeOut after page loaded*/
    console.log("document loaded!");
});
```

> **Note:** At first `display:none;` is not right. It should be `display: block;`. After page is loaded, then hide `.loader` tag.